# Node-modules Missing Directory

Tags: javascript, backend, npm-install, web-development-server

While I was coding I wanted to push to the github repo so I  deleted the node modules before pushing to the repo named abamade but now that I have pulled the same repo when I use npm i it shows this:

found 0 vulnerabilities

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

up to date, audited 3 packages in 4s

found 0 vulnerabilities

But after this I still don't have a node_modules directory in my folder

I was expecting to see the node modules directory to show

Answer (score 0):

If you have these packages from `node_modules` listed under `dependencies` in your `package.json` file, you can run `npm install` in your directory to install them.

Answer (score 0):

if You run `npm install` it should add the folder and install all dependencies in package.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).